# Foundation Accordion not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation accordion in my react component.

So this code works if get the component to render static HTML however, if I do it via loop the accordions are not clickable.

UL React code:

```
return (
<ul className="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed>
    this.state.test.map((data,index) => {
     return (<LI id={data.ID} value={data.Intro} />)
   }
</ul>
)
```

LI code

```
return (
            <li className="accordion-item" data-accordion-item  key={this.props.id}>
                <a href="#" className="accordion-title">{this.props.value}</a>
                <div className="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                    <strong>{this.props.value}</strong>
                    <p>Test</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
```

ComponentDidMount

```
new Accordion($(".accordion"), {
            slideSpeed: 500,
            multiExpand: true
        });
   fetch("URL")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState ({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items : [
                            { ID: 1, Intro: "Label sdf1" },
                            { ID: 2, Intro: "Label 2" },
                            { ID: 3, Intro: "Label 3" }
                        ]
                    })
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
```

Contructor

constructor(props){

```
     super(props);
       this.state = {
           alerts:[],
           items:[],

       }

 }
```

I have edited @Pavelcode [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj90n4q13q) to replicate my issue

Comment: Would you mind posting a sandbox for it so i could play with?

Comment: @BrianLe the API I am using to loop through LI is confidential and cant post it here, sorry about that. However, thats pretty much all the code except API

Comment: You shouldn't declare the `key` prop inside the `<Li />` component. Try doing it like this `return (<LI id={data.ID} value={data.Intro} key={yourKey} />)`

Comment: @BrianLe Did that, no luck :(

Comment: I think you are missing out some brackets as well. Have a quick look at `<Ul />` component

Comment: @BrianLe can you please point out the bracket?

Comment: `{this.state.test.map((data,index) => {
     return (<LI id={data.ID} value={data.Intro} />)
   })}`

Comment: @BrianLe I have reproduced the issue here https://codesandbox.io/s/oj90n4q13q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LI` component has broken markup, the `<a>` does not have a closing tag.

[image]

Should be `<a href="#" className="accordion-title">{this.props.value}</a>`.

EDIT:

The solution is in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/m76m5376ly?fontsize=14

Note that when using with React, Foundation must be initialized in one of the many ways described in the docs. In this example I used the `componentDidMount` to initialize the accordion.

Comment: it was missed while copying the code here, sorry fixed that still does not work

Comment: @Darty how are you importing the foundation library?

Comment: From `componentDidMount(){
        $(document).foundation();}` and it works with static HTML

Comment: @Darty Just updated the answer, I created the sandbox - check it out.

Comment: thanks for putting up the code. I think there is something wrong with my 'items' variable which is updated in the ComponentDidMount on API call.

Comment: I have added the componentDidMount code. Do you have any idea why its not working from there?

Comment: @Darty you need to re-initialize your accordion each time you set new items in the state, because the new markup will be generated. Separate the Accordion initialization in a separate method, and call it in the `componentDidUpdate` or after you set the new items into the state.